# Why element attribute change jQuery works on Firefox not on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have this jQuery that changes the name of the placeholder when a file is selected. This code works on Mozilla Firefox but not on Chrome. Any idea why?

```
$(".browswfile input").change(function(){
    $file = this.value;
    $file = $file.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '');
    $("#uploadFile").attr("placeholder",$file);
});
```

Moreover, I'm using this version of jquery API: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js 
Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer: Clear cache. That worked for me, just in case somebody is facing the same issue.